# WebKit border radius and transition bug

Tags: css, css-animations

In the latest stable release of Google Chrome: Version 31.0.1650.63 m (Canary also)  there is still a bug when there is a border radius and transition involved.
Content inside the element that has a border radius applied doesn't get clipped until the end of the animation.

I've managed to work it out by transitioning "top" and "left" properties instead of translateX / translateY

http://codepen.io/iki_xx/pen/wCFuo

However I can't seem to find a substitute for animating opacity.

http://codepen.io/iki_xx/pen/mspgE

Is there a fix for opacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it 2 ways:

```
  .thumb {
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    border: 10px solid red;
    border-radius:55px;
    &:hover {

        .caption {
       background-color:red;
        }
      }
  }
  .caption {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
       background-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 35px;
    @include transition(all 3s ease-in-out);
  }
```

a) setting border radius in the inner element

b) setting background-color: transparent and transitioning that

Comment: Using "background transparent" will do the trick.
Also, there is no need to set the border radius on the ".caption" element.
http://codepen.io/iki_xx/pen/HIcEJ

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, the easiest solution is to also provide a (slightly smaller) `border-radius` for your caption, like so:

```
.caption {
    ...
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

[See a demo of this fix](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tzhpq).

Comment: I've tried that, however it only works when the caption is the same color as the border, that won't always be the case.