# Rotate With Border Radius

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate an image in a div on hover while adding a border radius. It works perfectly until a transition is added.

Here is my css

```
.box{position:relative; height:300px; width:300px; display:block;overflow:hidden; }
img{position:relative;z-index:2; opacity:1;}
.box:hover img{border-radius:150px;-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);transform:rotateY(180deg);-webkit-transition:all .5s linear;transition:all .5s linear; }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="box">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZzgHX9M.jpg" alt="beach">
</div>
```

Here is a [demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IuxFG).

I could probably accomplish this with a background image, but for the purpose of the final project that wouldn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

***Note: There will eventually be a caption div inside the `.box` div***

Comment: I think you're hitting this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620441/webkit-border-radius-and-transition-bug

Comment: Try looking through here, it should have something along the lines of what you want http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/ --It has multiple pages

Answer (score 0):

Can't find a solution. Is the rotate functionality really important? Please see this fiddle if it is ok without rotate functionality.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aHvq/1/)

I just removed the `translate:rotateY`

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was going to use the `translate:rotateY` to reveal the caption div.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works in Chrome and Firefox- I specify the transition as "transform" instead of using "all". please let me know if this is helpful?

Here is the CSS:

```
.box{
position:relative;
height:300px; 
width:300px; 
display:block;
overflow:hidden; 
}
img{
position:relative;
z-index:2; 
opacity:1;
}
.box:hover img{
-webkit-border-radius: 150px; 
-moz-border-radius: 150px; 
border-radius:150px;    
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transition: transform .5s linear;
transition: transform .5s linear;
}
```