# Transition on transform with border radius and overflow hidden doesn't work in Safari

Tags: css, safari, hover, css-transitions

This might be a common issue, but I couldn't find the answer. Best way to understand the problem is to look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxvjejvk/

Basically I have a div with a `border-radius` and `overflow:hidden`. Inside the div is an image. When I hover over the div, I want the image to scale, using a transition. However, ***the border-radius of the div breaks*** (it doesn't have rounded corners anymore) for the duration of the animation.

Adding `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` to the div fixes this in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Safari. Does anyone know if there's a fix for this?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620441/webkit-border-radius-and-transition-bug

Comment: I don't see how that fixes my issue..

Comment: A partial fix is to use the image as a background image on an empty div instead of an `<img>` element. Or use a `-webkit-mask-image:` of a rounded rectangle.

Comment: Today I have the same issue on an Android device with Cordova (WebView Chrome). Weird, a few days before it worked well. But today suddenly not. Ok, maybe an automatic system software update. In my case I have svg elements animated in a overflow-hidden parent with border-radius to a circle. And when I animate transform-translate of the svg childs they become overlapped the border-radius (not the rectangle, only the radius). When I disable the animation in the DevTools the overflow-hidden works as well for the svg elements. Weird.... I don't know what happend. No updates in the log. No changes.

Comment: My workaround is to use margin or left / top to move the elements, instead of transform-translate. Currently it's not perfect. But I have to polish it. That bug is really annoying. 

Also see: https://forum.webflow.com/t/overflow-hidden-round-corners-not-working-on-safari/67805/3 (But in fact. It's also in Chrome (mobile)).

Comment: It's because the new Chrome v. 78. Corova uses this as WebView. If I disable (uninstall) it, it works again. Argh... So the Chrome WebView has a new bug.

Comment: Chrome v65 (and I guess the last version v77 more or less) works. But Chrome v78 not. Only on my Huawei M3 lite 10 Android 7. On another Device with Android 9 and same Chrome version it works. Maybe there are some hardware driver changes. My think this bug will never be fixed.

Comment: Or try https://stackoverflow.com/a/64885552/4997994

Answer (score 12):

You can fix it by adding webkit-mask-image for the parent element which has overflow:hidden

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```

Comment: Since a few days the bug is also present on Chrome / Chormium. On Android with Cordova (WebView). I tested it with an older version of Chrome. (v65) it works. The latest version (v78) does not work. Over the weekend the tabled updated it automatically. Nice surprise. -.- Thanks this workaround fixes the problem for this moment and this case. At the first I replaced the transform translate by left/top movement. This also fixes the problem. But in my case with some glitches and higher CPU usuage. The transform translate is much smoother because it uses GPU accel.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `will-change: transform;` to the `overfow: hidden` item works better for me on mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `border-radius` to parent element while hovering works for me.